# Removing the law of noncontradiction and paradoxes

Tags: logic, paradoxes

Plenty of work has been done in *intuitionistic logic*, where we remove from classical logic the law of excluded middle: $\vdash P \lor \lnot P$. However, what if we instead removed the law of noncontradiction: $\vdash \lnot (P \land \lnot P)$ ? In this logic, it would be possible for a proposition to be *both* true and false. This could also be viewed as a trivalent logic with three truth values: $\mathsf{T}$, $\mathsf{F}$, and $\mathsf{TF}$.

It seems then that Russell's paradox, for example, is no longer a paradox. If we construct $S = \{ x : x \notin x \}$ in naive set theory, and ask if $S \in S$, there is no contradiction - simply a proof that $S \in S$ is both true and false (has truth value $\mathsf{TF}$). Since most paradoxes are constructed the same way, would such a *contradictory logic* be immune to paradoxes? Are there still any paradoxes that arise?

---

**Edit:** If we modify Russell's paradox to
$$\begin{align*}
S\ &=\ \big\{ x: x \notin x \text{ and } \lnot (x \in x \text{ and } x \notin x) \big\} \\
&=\ \{ x: \operatorname{TV}(x \in x) = \mathsf{F} \text{ and } \operatorname{TV}(x \in x) \neq \mathsf{TF} \}
\end{align*}$$
where $\operatorname{TV}(\varphi)$ denotes the truth value of $\varphi$, do we now run into a contradiction?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The claim that (some) contradictions are both true and false is *dialetheism*. For an overview of dialethic logics, which allow true contradictions, see this [very useful encyclopaedia article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/). As you will see, the story is a tangled one, far too tangled to outline again here.

On the particular question as to whether we can save naive set theory by adopting a dialethic logic, there is an excellent discussion in Luca Incurvati's new book *Conceptions of Set* (CUP 2020). For a blog post discussing the relevant chapter, [see here](https://www.logicmatters.net/2020/04/30/luca-incurvatis-conceptions-of-set-4/). Short version: there's no version of dialethic logic which is both tolerably well motivated and yet can also give us a set theory with naive comprehension which is strong enough to be useful.